# How to do this effect in VB? It works in Python

Tags: vb.net

how can i fix this problem, in line with ">>" , in python it works, how does it work in vb

```
Public Class frmCafeOrder

  Public ingredients = {{"Apple", 10.0},
                        {"Lettuce", 12.5},
                        {"Tomato", 8.5},
                        {"Ham", 20.0},
                        {"Tuna", 18.5},
                        {"Grain Wheet", 8.0},
                        {"Honey Oat", 10.5}}

  Public priceControls = {{chkApple, lblApplePrice},
                          {chkLettuce, lblLettucePrice},
                          {chkTomato, lblTomatoPrice},
                          {chkHam, lblHamPrice},
                          {chkTuna, lblTunaPrice},
                          {rbGrainWheet, lblGrainWheetPrice},
                          {rbHoneyOat, lblHoneyOatPrice}}


  Private Sub frmCafeOrder_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    init()
    For i As Integer = 0 To ingredients.GetLength(0)
        Dim ingredient = ingredients(i, 0)
        >>Dim controls = priceControls(i)
        Dim price = ingredients(i, 1)
        >>priceControls = controls(i)
        >>priceControls = String.Format("HK$ {0}", price)

    Next
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: didn't work, i want my form load all the ingredients prices following the priceControls array

Comment: You should learn to use classes to organize your data.  I *think* you are looking to cast your label: `DirectCast(priceControls(i, 1), Label).Text = String.Format("HK$ {0}", ingredients(i, 1))`

Comment: ">>" is showing a line i think it had to be fix to let the program run what i expected

Comment: thx a lot, let me give it a try

Comment: @EricLeung That code totally scares me ; no typing at all (I wonder how many error adding `Option Strict On` at top of file would give) ; both ingredients and priceControls are `Object(,)` that is a 2D array of Object. That's why you get the errors when trying to use only one index where a pair is needed. After that they probably will be type and cast problems as said by @LarsTech. (me wonders why the Init instead of using the class ctor too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are trying to use a 2D array without specifying the other dimension.

You specify these perfectly:

```
    Dim ingredient = ingredients(i, 0)
    Dim price = ingredients(i, 1)
```

but are failing to do that with this:

```
    Dim controls = priceControls(i) 'notice it's missing the second dimension
```

Secondly.... this... whatever this is...

```
Dim controls = priceControls(i)
priceControls = controls(i)
```

You are setting controls to priceControls and then trying to set it to itself, but with an added (i), where on earth did the (i) in controls come from?

and then for a little added confusion.

```
priceControls = controls(i)
priceControls = String.Format("HK$ {0}", price)
```

why set it to one thing when you are just going to set it to another?

What I am guessing you are trying to do is this:

1. Go through the list of ingredients in Ingredients()
2. Populate the right lbl.text field with the corresponding price

   ```
   For i As Integer = 0 To ingredients.GetLength(0)
       Dim ingredient as String = ingredients(i, 0)
       Dim price as String = ingredients(i, 1)
       Dim lbl as Label = DirectCast(priceControls(i, 1), Label)
       lbl.text = String.Format("HK$ {0}", price)
   Next
   ```

You haven't really specified the problem directly or what you are looking to do, so this is really just my guess at both.